# Conexão PHP e SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server, conexão

Estou tentando realizar uma conexão com o SQLServer e PHP
Mas a página me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 192.168.2.7\SRVDOC\DOCSYSTEMSCAN in C:\wamp\www\conexao.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mssql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\conexao.php on line 3

O código atual é:

```php
<?php
    $con = mssql_connect("192.168.2.7\SRVDOC\DOCSYSTEMSCAN", "sa", "minhasenha");
    mssql_select_db("fd_585b0f87", $con);
 ?>
```

Estou quebrando a cabeça mas não sei oque pode ser... Alguma sugestão?
Obrigado.

Comment: é SQL Express ?

Comment: Olá, Não amigo SQL completo

Comment: coloque somente o ip não dá ?

Comment: Isso é uma duvida que tenho... Ali eu devo colocar o servidor...Mas oque vem a ser?O ip ou o server name que realizo o login no SQLServer?

Comment: `<?php 
$conn = mssql_connect("ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS", "usuario", "senha") or die ("erro ao conectar");` aonde ADMIN-PC é o nome da sua máquina e SQLEXPRESS o nome da sua instância do SQL Server. É igual quando você ta entrando pelo Gerenciador do SQL Server

Comment: Cara, você configurou o SqlServer para este tipo de conexão antes. É necessário liberar a porta 1433 e a forma de conexão por ip, dentro do SqlServer.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, tente seguir o modelo proposto na página oficial do manual PHP:

```
$serverName = "SRVDOC\DOCSYSTEMSCAN"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"fd_585b0f87", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"minhasenha");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Ou tente dessa forma com a função "mssql_connect"

```
$server = 'SRVDOC\DOCSYSTEMSCAN';
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'minhasenha');
```

Referência: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o que está escrito na documentação da função [`mssql_select_db`](http://www.php.net//manual/pt_BR/function.mssql-select-db.php) uma **provável** causa deste erro pode ser o *underscore* contido no nome do banco de dados.

> Para escapar o nome de um banco de dados que contenha espaços, hifens ("-"), ou quaisquer outros caracteres excepcionais, o nome do banco de dados deve estar entre colchetes, como é mostrado no exemplo abaixo. Esta técnica também deve ser aplicada ao selecionar um nome de banco de dados que contenha uma palavra reservada (como *primary*).

Para *escapar* o caractere coloque o `fd_585b0f87` entre colchetes, assim:

```php
<?php
    $con = mssql_connect("192.168.2.7\SRVDOC\DOCSYSTEMSCAN", "sa", "minhasenha") 
    or die ("Erro ao conectar-se ao BD: ".mssql_get_last_message());
    mssql_select_db('[fd_585b0f87]', $con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia tentar utilizar o [PDO para SQLServer](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

```
<?php
  try {
    $hostname = "myhost";
    $port = 10060;
    $dbname = "tempdb";
    $username = "dbuser";
    $pw = "password";
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}
```